# How can I calculate the sensitivity of a seismometer?

Tags: velocity, geophysics, signal-processing, sensor, instrument

I would like to know how to find the minimum ground motion a seismometer can measure, specifically if a certain seismometer can measure 1 micron/sec velocity. I have a few specs from the datasheet but I'm not a seismologist and am trying to figure out how to relate the specs to one another.

```
Velocity output band: 30s (0.03Hz) to 100 Hz
Output Sensitivity: 2400 V/m/s
Peak/Full scale output: Differential: +- 20V 
Sensor dynamic range: 137 dB @ 5 Hz
```

What I initially tried was dividing `Peak/Full Scale Output` by `Output Sensitivity` but the number seems too large.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The "Peak/Full" looks to be the dynamic range in physical units (i.e., volts) and the "Sensor dynamic range" is the same thing in normalized units (i.e., decibels above some background/reference value) at a specific frequency (there will be a complex transfer function describing the frequency response).  I am guessing that the speeds involved here must be standardized, i.e., seismic waves at a given frequency propagate at a given speed (look up seismic wave dispersion relations).

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic range in system design describes the relationship between full scale output to the noise floor.  Signal levels below the noise floor cannot be measured directly.  If the signal path is digitized the digital resolution would normally be taken into account for the noise floor assessment.

The full scale range in voltage is +/- 20V which equates to 20/2400 = 0.00833(m/s) of full scale velocity.
The 137 dB dynamic range means the noise floor is 0.00833 (m/s) / 10^(137/20) = 1.17 e-9 (m/s)